# Paypal IPN returns INVALID response

Tags: vb.net, paypal-ipn

```
{Following is the vb.net code for IPN listener:
    If Me.TestMode = True Then
            Me.RequestUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        Else
            Me.RequestUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" '"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        End If



        '====================================Test======================================'
        Dim startTime As String = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss:tt}", Now)
        '=============================================================================='

        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(Me.RequestUrl), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim Param() As Byte = HttpContext.Current.Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength)
        Dim strRequest As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param)
        strRequest = strRequest & "&cmd=_notify-validate"
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length
        ' Dim pairs() As String = strRecieved.Split("&")
        Using streamOut As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII)
            streamOut.Write(strRequest.ToString)
            streamOut.Close()
        End Using
        Dim streamIn As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Dim strResponse As String = streamIn.ReadToEnd()
        streamIn.Close()
        WriteLog(strResponse)
```

I have done code for paypal IPN listener in vb.net . When I test that url with paypal sandbox account, it shows following message:
"IPN successfully sent."
But when I check my log file on server, then it shows INVALID response from paypal sandbox url. Without VALID response my other code will not work. 
Please help!!

Comment: IPN message is sent when any event happens with paypal transaction. how and where ipn message appear "IPN successfully sent".

Comment: When I test it with paypal sandbox simulator. At that time I am getting "IPN successfully sent" message.

Comment: do one test transaction on paypal sandbox, in this way paypal will send you ipn response with valid status.

Comment: It starts working when I specify "notify_url(IPN url here)" while migrating control from my site to paypal. But by doing this I got payment_status=pending, although I have made payment. Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: I am posting code which may help you to generate paypal payment link and once transaction completed, you will got ipn response properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate paypal transaction like e.g buy now button via vb.net

```
Public Shared Function GetPayPalPaymentUrl(item_name As String, item_number As String, amount As String, quantity As String, username As String) As String
Dim strURL As String = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
If PaypalBLL.Paypal_Live_Status() = 1 Then
    strURL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
End If
Dim BaseUrl As String = Config.GetUrl()
Dim cancel_url As String = BaseUrl + "paypal/cancel.aspx"
Dim return_url As String = BaseUrl + "paypal/confirmation.aspx"
Dim notifyUrl As String = BaseUrl + "paypal/ipn.aspx"
'string image_url = ""
Dim image_url As String = ""
' paypal header url
Dim paypal_logo As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(BaseUrl + "images/logo.png")
Dim Url As New StringBuilder()
Dim CustomFieldValue As String = username
'User-defined field which PayPal passes through the system and returns to you in your merchant payment notification email. Subscribers do not see this field.
Url.Append(strURL + "?cmd=_xclick&upload=1&rm=2&no_shipping=1&no_note=1&currency_code=USD&business=" + PaypalBLL.Paypal_Receiver_Email() + "&item_number=" + item_number + "&item_name=" + item_name + "&amount=" + amount + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&undefined_quantity=0&notify_url=" + notifyUrl + "&return=" + return_url + "&cancel_return=" + cancel_url + "&cpp_header_Image=" + image_url + "&cpp_headerback_color=ECDFDF&cpp_headerborder_color=A02626&cpp_payflow_color=ECDFDF&image_url=" + paypal_logo + "&custom=" + CustomFieldValue + "")
Return Url.ToString()
End Function
```

Generate paypal link, when you click on link, you will be redirect to paypal sandbox or live link. once you complete transaction, you will be redirected to website back and within background paypal will send transaction event via ipn.

Hope you will receive proper ipn response.

Comment: I have done all this code and it is working fine, now problem comes when I made payment I recieved IPN response as "payment_status=Pending". Without getting "completed" status I can't proceed ahead.

Comment: well payment_status=pending sent by paypal, then trasaction should be in pending status. check transaction status in paypal transaction detail page.

Comment: Transaction is in pending stage with pending_reason=unilateral. I am googling it to sort it out.

Comment: unilateral: The payment is pending because it was made to an email
address that is not yet registered or confirmed. please make sure you created test email address via developer.paypal.com and use it properly for transactions.

Comment: Yes Irfan that was the only reason, Thanks alot for your timely support.